# Stack requires same package for each project due to .ghci

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Since recently i started using imports in my `.ghci` file to colorize my code. Since Stack uses a separate set of libraries for each project i now have to require `HsColour` for each project. Even though `HsColour` is not actually used by the code in the project. How can i let `stack ghci` make use of the same `HsColour` each time without interfering with the project libraries? If this is not possible, is there an alternative to this problem?

Comment: `HsColour` is both an executable and a library. Stack and other tools will use the *executable* to actually colorize code in your terminal, your editor, etc. Install the executable (by building as usual, then copying the executable) in a directly in your `PATH`. "i now have to require HsColour for each project" - doesn't really make sense, as project dependencies are what *your* code needs, not what stack needs as part of its toolchain....

Comment: @user2407038 At first I thought the same thing as you, but it does seem that colourising GHCi in the manner described by the OP requires the library, and not the executable. Cf. [this r/haskell post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/144biy/pretty_output_in_ghci_howto_in_comments/).

Comment: @duplode I agree in principle that it can be accomplished this way, but if you are depending on the library then you are depending on the library, period. That means recompiling the source code every time there's a chance it could have change and for every single project which depends on it. The `HsColour` *executable* allows you to *not* depend on the source code. The answer to "How can i let stack ghci make use of the same HsColour each time without interfering with the project libraries?" is "Use the HsColour executable". @OP You might have to add your function and recompile HsColour.

Comment: @user2407038 Indeed. Still, it would make sense if stack provided a way to manage "dependencies" of this sort, which are not dependencies of the project (they are never actually linked by project code) but merely of the stack/cabal/GHC environment -- I can imagine, for instance, stack ensuring `HsColour` is installed every time you switch to a new resolver/snapshot. (I think there is currently no way to do that, though I might be missing something.)

Comment: @user2407038 i tried HsColour as executable, it caused weird alignment of things in ghci. Also i use the `groom` library, and in the future possibly more libraries, so my original question still stands.

Comment: @duplode I think stack does give you a way to manage executables - `stack exec` - for example, if you install a package globally with `stack install <pkg>` and that package builds an executable, that executable will be available with `stack exec <executable-name>` in the global environment and any package using that environment. You can then have e.g. `alias HsColour='stack exec HsColour --'` which will always use your local project environment (in fact I use `alias ghci='stack exec ghci --'`)

Comment: @Flip Have you tried adding `hscolour` to `extra-deps` in the global config file? It seems to work for me (at least, for other libraries) - I can run `stack exec ghci` and the imports in the `.ghci` file are recognized properly.

Comment: @user2407038 yes that works only if you are not starting ghci in a project directory